# Change JS alert to DOM error message div

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, alert

I need to convert my error messaging to a positioned div (hidden initially) instead of the standard js alert. I realize I need to push the alert message to the DOM, but I'm new to javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Additionally, I need to do it without a confirm (so error message removes on field focus)

```
if(el != null) {
                switch(el.name) {
                    case "firstName":              
                        //First Name Field Validation, Return false if field is empty
                        if( f.firstName.value == "" )
                        {
                            alert( bnadd_msg_002 );
                            if ((typeof TeaLeaf != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client.tlAddEvent != "undefined") ) {
                                var nVO = { ErrorMessage : bnadd_msg_002} 
                                var subtype="CustomErrorMsg";
                                TeaLeaf.Event.tlAddCustomEvent(subtype, nVO);
                                    }
                            return false; 
                        }
                        break;
```

Comment: By convert do you mean displaying the error messages in a div

Comment: @Balanivash - yes, right now js validation is using standard js alert. I need to show the error message dynamically in a div on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach using jQuery

```
function customAlert(msg){
   var div = $("#AlertMessage");
   if (div.length == 0) {
     div = $("<div id='AlertMessage' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
     $("body").prepend(div);
   } 
   div.html(msg)
}
```

CSS

```
#WriteProperties {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 300px;  
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px; /* position as desired */
    top: 90px; /* position as desired */
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

JS for clearing message on focus of a text input field. You can always be more selective about which fields to attach the event to.

```
$("input[type='text']").live("focus", function(){
  $("#AlertMessage").hide();
})
```

Comment: How does this work with my code above. Not sure how to incorporate the two with the dynamically loaded error message.

Comment: just replace this line  alert( bnadd_msg_002 ); with customAlert (bnadd_msg_002); .... there are better ways to do this but this is a simple replacement for what you are already using.

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite what you have, you would additionally assign window.alert = customAlert; and it would seamlessly override all your alert statements.

Comment: Works great - I made some changes to the jquery bit to get it to do some other things - my only issue now is clearing out the error message on focus for the input field.

Comment: I updated with some more code. Thank you for marking it answered, you might consider upvoting any answers that were useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

very basic but sshould give you a good direction to go.
Basically your creating a div that is hidden, and then you'll fill the span inside wiht your text and show the div.

```
<Div id="myalertbox" style='display:none'>
<span>put message here</span>
</div>
```

I always use jquery to change the DOM around. Makes thing alot simpler.

```
jquery("#myalertbox span").text(bnadd_msg_002);
jquery("#myalertbox").show();
```

Then just use CSS to position the DIV.
probably have to set the DIV to position Absolute, then use top and left to place it in the middle of the screen.

```
You may need to surround the DIV with another DIV.
<div id="grayout">
<Div id="myalertbox" style='display:none'>
<span>put message here</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Show the gray out div full screen, but set its transpancy.
Basically will block people from clicking the screen while your error message shows.

Or just get jquery and it has a built in error message box.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.error/

Comment: Interesting - does the dynamic error message, using the jquery approach, need to be on page - or can I call an external file? (or array)?

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library. It is a seperate .js file you can get for free from the jquery site. You reference it on everypage you would like to use it. But basically behind the scenes, jquery will create the DIV for you and all the css. It does so much, especially wiht dom and events. plus works cross browser very well.

Comment: What Bobby Borszich has below, is the same simple idea, and avoid learning jquery. I can't give him a +1 yet.

Comment: jquery I understand, it was the put message here bit, that I have to load dynamically from a list of error messages